# Head of office or office manager?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I'm curious about the difference between "head of office" and "office manager". As far as I can see, they both refer to pretty much the same job, but I get the feeling that "head of office" is the title, whereas "office manager" is the name of the job. Am I right about this, or could either be used bot as a title and as the name of the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An office manager plans and organises work in an office.

The head of an office is the senior person in an office.

Office management is something that the head of an office might be expected to do.  So the head of an office may well be the office manager. Or the head of an office might hire someone to do office management for them.

Comment: Ah, so not necessarily the same job then... But yeah, this makes sense and explains why I had the impression that "head of office" was more of a title :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting differences on either side of the pond.

In America, you generally will not hear "head of office". Leaders tend to have titles that more precisely describe what they presumably do. "Director of Sales", "Engineering Manager", "Regional Marketing Manager", "Technical Lead", "Research Manager - Western Division", etc.

Perhaps more interestingly, "Office Manager" now frequently means what the term "secretary" used to mean. They are usually the one who answer phones, make printouts, organize snack carts, make sure the coffee machine has filters, get cake and make sure everyone signs the card for an employee's birthday, etc. In this context, such Office Managers direct the general functions of the office space itself, rather than manage people or work-oriented projects.

Comment: Wow – this is interesting! Thanks for this!